# Fancytree - Add new items into a tree node (date, notes, etc)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Fancytree has a way to add new items into a tree node?

In the demos you can see only the "title" displayed but I want to add "date" and "notes".

I know I can doit with the *table extension* and `renderColumns` but I want to sort the info in a different way and I can't change the linear structure of a table with CSS only.

I prefer use `<div>` or `<span>` elements instead of a `<table>` to sort and add CSS to this.

I think this HTML structure for every `<li>` element in the tree will be perfect:

```
<li>
    <span class="fancytree-node fancytree-exp-n fancytree-ico-c">
        <span class="fancytree-expander"></span>
        <span class="fancytree-icon"></span>
        <span class="fancytree-title">Sub-item 4.1</span>
        <span class="fancytree-date">21-5-2015</span>
        <span class="fancytree-note">This is a note inside a Fancytree node</span>
    </span>
</li>
```

Here you have a jsfiddle with a JSON with the Google Tasks API structure that populate a Fancytree.

http://jsfiddle.net/prncw2sL/11/

If you go inside the JSON with this link:

http://res.cloudinary.com/neuropro/raw/upload/v1431196887/JSONGoogleTasksAIP_aevrz8.json

.. you will see that in the task with ID `MTYwNzEzNjc2OTEyMDI1MzcwNzM6ODUwNjk4NTgzOjg4ODk2MDI0MQ` has a `due` with the date I want to add to the tree node.

Also in the same task you will see a `notes` item. This is the other content I want to add to the tree node.

Some ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi @Andrew ! No, I don't have it but I can do it. Do you prefer one with the table and the `date` and `notes` elements inside or just the tree to add this elements?

Comment: Hi again @Andrew, I was editing the question to add a jsfiddle as you ask. This is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/prncw2sL/11/ Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass html as `node.title`, so you could generate markup like

```
<span class="fancytree-node fancytree-exp-n fancytree-ico-c">
    <span class="fancytree-expander"></span>
    <span class="fancytree-icon"></span>
    <span class="fancytree-title">
        <span class="ft-header">Sub-item 4.1</span>
        <span class="ft-date">21-5-2015</span>
        <span class="ft-note">This is a note inside a Fancytree node</span>
    </span>
</span>
```

Alternatively implement the `renderTitle` or `renderNode` events and modify the markup using jQuery.

```
renderNode: function(event, data) {
    // Optionally tweak data.node.span
    $(data.node.span).text(">>" + data.node.title);
},
renderTitle: function(event, data) {
    // When defined, must return a HTML string for the node title
    return "new title";
},
```

Comment: Thanks @mar10 ! I was use the `renderNode` event with the `$(data.node.span).html( YourHTMLHere );` inside. The code now is working perfect.